# Can I enter Wrestlemania?

Tags: wwe-2k18

When I did a 10-man Royal Rumble, my custom character won. And it said I had a title opportunity at Wrestlemania. But can I do a Wrestlemania event?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on which mode you're playing, If you are playing on career mode then you'll have to wait for Wrestlemania to come around and you should be in the Title match.

If you are playing in Universe mode, you can either keep playing or Sim the calendar a few months until you get to Wrestlemania and you'll be in the title match.

If you just did a 10 Man exhibition royal rumble match, then sure, you can select Title match from the Match choices and then set the arena to one of the Wrestlemania Arenas whenever you want.

Comment: i am just doing a normal one on one. no career or anything. for my custom character.

Comment: Then in the match selection menu, pick any match type and then set the arena to Wrestlemania 33. Then, there should be an option to make it a title match, select that and choose the title you want to compete for. Then when you've done all of that, select your custom character to play as and the champion as your opponent and away you go.